# Я делаю оператор ++ добавляет/отнимает 1 к каждому органу вектора. никак не могу понять почему не видит оператор ++ и --

Tags: c++

> error C2676: binary '++': 'Vector' does not define this operator or a
>   conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
>
> error C2676: binary '--': 'Vector' does not define this operator or a
>   conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

```
include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Vector
{
  private:
    int* first;
    int* second;
  public:
    Vector(int f = 0, int s = 0); //Constructor
    Vector(const Vector& other); //Copy Constructor
    ~Vector(); //Destructor

    //SETTERS, GETTERS
    int* getFirst();
    int* getSecond();
    void setFirst(int* f);
    void setSecond(int* s);
    Vector operator ++ (); // Overloaded ++ operator
    Vector operator -- (); // Overloaded -- operator
};

Vector Vector :: operator ++ ()   // Overloaded ++ operator
{
    first++;
    second++;
    return *this;
}

Vector Vector :: operator -- ()   // Overloaded -- operator
{
    --first;
    --second;
    return *this;
}


int main()
{
    int first, second;
    cout << "Please enter the first vector (first , second ) : ";
    cin >> first >> second;
    Vector v1(first, second);
    cout << "Please enter the second vector (first , second ) : ";
    cin >> first >> second;
    Vector v2(first, second);
    cout << "The vector you've entered is: ";
    v1.print();
    cout << "  ";
    v2.print();
    v1++;
    v2++;
    v1.print();
    cout << "  ";
    v2.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто - **префиксный** `++` определяется как

```
operator ++ ();
```

а **постфиксный** - как

```
operator ++ (int);
```

Исправьте или определение оператора, или вызов `v++` замените на `++v`.

Comment: спасибо большое за объяснение

Comment: @Poli Ну, если вас ответ устраивает - помечайте птичкой :)

Answer (score -1):

Просто дам свой класс вектора, когда-то делал - можешь взять весь класс, а можешь по аналогии переделать:

.Н

```
typedef struct Vector2 {

public:
    Vector2();
    Vector2(float value);
    Vector2(float x, float y);
    Vector2 operator+(const Vector2& ROperand);
    Vector2 operator-(const Vector2& ROperand);
    Vector2 operator*(const Vector2& ROperand);
    Vector2 operator/(const Vector2& ROperand);
    Vector2 operator++();
    Vector2 operator++(int);
    Vector2 operator+=(float var);
    Vector2 operator--();
    Vector2 operator--(int);
    Vector2 operator-=(float var);
    bool operator>(const Vector2& ROperand);
    bool operator>=(const Vector2& ROperand);
    bool operator<(const Vector2& ROperand);
    bool operator<=(const Vector2& ROperand);
    bool operator==(const Vector2& ROperand);
    bool operator!=(const Vector2& ROperand);
    bool operator!=(float var);
    float x, y;
    //V4 vec4XY();
    //V4 vec4WH();
}V2;
```

.срр

```
#include "Vector2.h"


Vector2::Vector2() 
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

Vector2::Vector2(float value)
{
    x = value;
    y = value;
}

Vector2::Vector2(float x, float y) 
{

    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

//V4 Vector2::vec4XY()
//{
//  return V4(x,y,0,0);
//}
//
//V4 Vector2::vec4WH()
//{
//  return V4(0,0,x,y);
//}

Vector2 Vector2::operator+(const Vector2& ROperand) {

    Vector2 Result;
    Result.x = x + ROperand.x;
    Result.y = y + ROperand.y;
    return Result;
}

Vector2 Vector2::operator-(const Vector2& ROperand) {

    Vector2 Result;
    Result.x = x - ROperand.x;
    Result.y = y - ROperand.y;
    return Result;
}

Vector2 Vector2::operator*(const Vector2& ROperand) {

    Vector2 Result;
    Result.x = x * ROperand.x;
    Result.y = y * ROperand.y;
    return Result;
}

Vector2 Vector2::operator/(const Vector2& ROperand) {

    Vector2 Result;
    Result.x = x / ROperand.x;
    Result.y = y / ROperand.y;
    return Result;
}

Vector2 Vector2::operator++() {

    Vector2 Result;
    Result.x = ++x,
    Result.y = ++y;
    return Result;
}

Vector2 Vector2::operator++(int)
{
    Vector2 Result;
    Result.x = x++,
    Result.y = y++;
    return Result;
}

Vector2 Vector2::operator--() {

    Vector2 Result;
    Result.x = --x,
    Result.y = --y;
    return Result;
}

Vector2 Vector2::operator--(int)
{
    Vector2 Result;
    Result.x = x--,
    Result.y = y--;
    return Result;
}

bool Vector2::operator>(const Vector2& ROperand) {

    if ((x > ROperand.x) , (y > ROperand.y))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

bool Vector2::operator>=(const Vector2& ROperand) {

    if ((x >= ROperand.x) , (y >= ROperand.y))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

bool Vector2::operator<(const Vector2& ROperand) {

    if ((x < ROperand.x) , (y < ROperand.y))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

bool Vector2::operator<=(const Vector2& ROperand) {

    if (x <= ROperand.x , (y <= ROperand.y))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

bool Vector2::operator==(const Vector2& ROperand) {

    if ((x == ROperand.x) , (y == ROperand.y))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

bool Vector2::operator!=(const Vector2& ROperand) {

    if ((x != ROperand.x) , (y != ROperand.y))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

bool Vector2::operator!=(float var) {

    if (!((x == var) ,  (y == var)))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

Vector2 Vector2::operator+=(float var) {

    Vector2 Result;
    Result.x = x += var;
    Result.y = y += var;
    return Result;
}

Vector2 Vector2::operator-=(float var) {

    Vector2 Result;
    Result.x = x -= var;
    Result.y = y -= var;
    return Result;
}
```